# Can not get rid of Shift-Key in NSMenuItem Modifier Mask

Tags: swift, keyboard, shortcut, nsmenuitem

I have a NSMenuItem that has a keyboard shortcut.
I set the shortcut like this:

```
        // Close
    let closeItem = NSMenuItem()
    closeItem.title = Resources.QUIT
    closeItem.action = #selector(quit)
    closeItem.keyEquivalentModifierMask = [NSCommandKeyMask]
    closeItem.keyEquivalent = "Q"
    self.menu.addItem(closeItem)
```

Unfortunately, I can not get rid of the "Shift" key:

[image: Result]

What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution was pretty easy: Instead of using "Q", I used "q" and the shift modifier was gone.
The new code:

```
self.menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: Resources.QUIT, action: #selector(quit), keyEquivalent: "q"))
```

Comment: Nice catch. Worked for me too. Can you mark the answer as the correct one?

Comment: spent almost 30 minutes being confused by this not knowing why. Thank you!!